# ElasticSearch Unable to find on disk file script

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a groovy script using Java API:

```
AggregationBuilders
    .terms(this.getName())
    .field(this.getName())
    .script(
        new Script(
            "year",
            ScriptType.FILE,
            "groovy",
            ImmutableMap.of("name", this.getName())
        )
    );
```

I'm running an elasticsearch instance using a custom made docker image. This is the DockerFile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:2.4
MAINTAINER me

COPY ./year.groovy /etc/elasticsearch/scripts
```

As you can see I'm providing my script file `COPY`ing the file in `/etc/elaticsearch/scripts`.

I've checked out on `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts`:

```
#docker exec -it es ls /etc/elasticsearch/scripts -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 70 Oct  6 07:24 year.groovy
```

However, when the java code is reached, it's telling me:

```
Unable to find on disk file script [year] using lang [groovy];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in your configuration?

Comment: As far I've been able to figure out, script files are enabled by default. Dynamic scripting is refering to `inline` scripts, isn't it?

Comment: dynamic scripting can be enabled for inline, file and indexed scripts. You probably need to enable file scripts with `script.file: true`

Comment: `script.file` is set to `true` by default. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Comment: @OrWeinberger just making sure this wasn't overlooked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elasticsearch docker image uses different default paths, looking at the relevant [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/e74f9ba98e26221af4a3103d65ff519621e989d2/2.4/Dockerfile) I can see that it has a reference to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts`, try placing your groovy script there and see if that works.